# $\lim _n \mathbb P(X_n>\varepsilon) \equiv 0$ implies $\lim _n\mathbb P(X_n>0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory

Suppose it holds that $\lim _n\mathbb P(X_n >\varepsilon) = 0$ for every $\varepsilon >0$. Does it follow that $\lim _n\mathbb P(X_n>0) =0$?

[removed nonsense argument]

Is the initial statement false in general? If necessary $X_n$ iid may be assumed.

Comment: Consider $X_n$ that is uniformly distributed on $[0,n]$, with a pdf equal to $1/n$ there. Take a look at proofs or  examples and counterexamples for the dominated convergence theorem for possibilities.

Comment: Or just try it when the $X_n$ are constant variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the iid assumption, the $\lim_n$ does nothing, so we simply have $\Bbb P(X>\epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Thus does indeed imply $\Bbb P(X>0)=0$.

Without iid, consider $X_n$ with uniform distribution on $[0,1/n]$. Then $\Bbb P(X_n>\epsilon)=0$ for $n\gg0$, but $\Bbb P(X_n>0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, very obvious in hindsight, I feel like such an idiot sometimes..